# Open Sublime 3 from Mac Terminal

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I was following "[Launch Sublime Text 2 or 3 from the Mac OSX Terminal](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal)" to open Sublime from Terminal.

I typed `open ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal. The first time it opened a text editor with a line like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I changed it to

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$/usr/local/bin
```

Now, when I type

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

in the terminal, it shows "command not found" and in the terminal if I type

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Sublime will not pop up. But if I take `open` off, like

```
type /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Sublime will just open.

And now, if I type `clear` in the terminal to clear the previous codes, Terminal shows "command not found".

Is there are anything I can do to revert back?